# Slicing hash of hashes perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, slice, hash

I am using hash of hashes on my program.  I want to sum two values in the same line.
Example of my hash is:

```
%data_final = (
   2010 => { 
      Jan => {
        group1 => {
           Type1 => {
              Total1 => 12,
              Total2 => 10
           },
           Type2 => {
              Total1 => 17,
              Total2 => 14
           },
       },
     },
   }
);
```

I want to have a big Total of Total1  and Total2 for group1. I am doing the following:

```
$total1_sum = sum( @{$data_final}{2010}{Jan}{group1}}{qw/Type1 Type2}{Total1} );
$total2_sum = sum( @{$data_final}{2010}{Jan}{group1}}{qw/Type1 Type2}{Total2} );
```

Output of $total1_sum should be 29 and $total2_sum should be 24,
but I got a syntax error near "}{".

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This is a hash of hashes of hashes of hashes of hashes.  Might be time to reconsider your data structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@h{@k}{Total1}` makes no sense. You mean to iterate over each reference returned by the slice and grab the value of an element of the referenced hash, but you neglected to employ any form of looping. `map` is convenient here.

After applying `map` and fixing your misplaced `}`, you get:

```
my $total1_sum = sum map $_->{Total1},
   @{ $data_final{2010}{Jan}{group1} }{qw( Type1 Type2 )};
my $total2_sum = sum map $_->{Total2},
   @{ $data_final{2010}{Jan}{group1} }{qw( Type1 Type2 )};
```

Let's factor out the common bits:

```
my @results = @{ $data_final{2010}{Jan}{group1} }{qw( Type1 Type2 )};
my $total1_sum = sum map $_->{Total1}, @results;
my $total2_sum = sum map $_->{Total2}, @results;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, that will do the trick :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use strict; use warnings;  

my %data_final = (
   2010 => {
      Jan => {
        group1 => {
           Type1 => {
              Total1 => 12,
              Total2 => 10
           },
           Type2 => {
              Total1 => 17,
              Total2 => 14
           },
       },
     },
   }
);

my $total1_sum;
$total1_sum += $data_final{2010}{Jan}{group1}{$_}{Total1}
    for keys $data_final{2010}{Jan}{group1};

my $total2_sum;
$total2_sum += $data_final{2010}{Jan}{group1}{$_}{Total2}
    for keys $data_final{2010}{Jan}{group1};

print <<EOF;
total1_sum=$total1_sum
total2_sum=$total2_sum
EOF
```

**Output** :

```
total1_sum=29
total2_sum=24
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. The other answer fits better the way that I programmed the big program.  Using Excel::Writer::XLSX;

Answer (score 1):

Found a couple of issues in your code:

```
$total1_sum = sum( @{$data_final}{2010}{Jan}{group1}}{qw/Type1 Type2}{Total1} );
                                ^ extra }                           ^ missing /
```

Also, the slice returns a list of hashrefs, which you cannot access directly, so the `{Total1}` part on the end needs to be changed into a `map` (or a loop).

Final corrected code:

```
$total1_sum = sum( map { $_->{Total1} } @{$data_final{2010}{Jan}{group1}}{qw/Type1 Type2/} );
$total2_sum = sum( map { $_->{Total2} } @{$data_final{2010}{Jan}{group1}}{qw/Type1 Type2/} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems.

1. You're missing the terminator for **qw** (you need `{qw/Type1 Type2/}`). I assume that part was just an oversight.
2. There shouldn't be a **}** after **$data_final**. If, for example, you just wanted to get the value of the 2010 key, it would be `$data_final{2010}`, not `{$data_final}{2010}`. Then, to get the value for a key in the hash contained in that value, tack another subscript onto that: `$data_final{2010}{Jan}` ...and so on. So, your hash slice should be `@{$data_final{2010}{Jan}{group1}}{qw/Type1 Type2/}`.
3. A hash slice returns an array, as implied (actually, necessitated) by the **@**. The array returned by this particular hash slice does contain hashes, but you can't just tack a hash subscript to an array of hashes to get an array of the values of the corresponding key in each hash. For example, if you have an array **@harray** that contains hashes, `@harray{mykey}` won't return an array of the values of **mykey** in each hash. But that's what you're trying to do with the `{Total1}` and `{Total2}` at the end. So, what you need to do is iterate over the hash slice and sum up the values of the given key.

There may be more compact ways to do it, but this works:

```
foreach (@{$data_final{2010}{Jan}{group1}}{qw/Type1 Type2/}) {
  $total1_sum += $$_{Total1};
}
foreach (@{$data_final{2010}{Jan}{group1}}{qw/Type1 Type2/}) {
  $total2_sum += $$_{Total2};
}
```

The **$$** is to dereference, because the array's elements are actually hash references.